# Adding row to relational table - linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, primary-key

I have 3 primary Tables -  `Picture, Album and Collage`. `Collage` and `Album` can have 1-many pictures. Pictures do not have to be in `Album` to be added to the `Collage`.

To define their relationship, I have `AlbumPicture` and `CollagePicture` tables.

My problem is when I try to add picture already uploaded to the `Collage` and hence to the `CollagePicture` table. It throws primry key violation error on `PK_Picture` since picture already exists.

```
CollagePictures.InsertOnSubmit(new CollagePicture {Collage = CollagePicture = existingPic});
```

I need to add one record in `CollagePicture` for existing picture and new `Collage`. Is there any way I can tell linq to not add picture if it already exists?

I am new to Linq and still learning.

EDIT:
sorry If I was not clear.
I assign PK to Picture as GUID when Pictures are uploaded. In CollagePicture I already have this pictureId with different collage

e.g.

```
CollagePictureId [PK]= 1
CollageId=1
PictureId = 1234567890123456
```

Now I want to add same Picture with different CollageId say,2. When I try to add anything to `CollagePicture` it tries to add to the `Picture` table as well. and that is when I get an exception. Hope this will clear things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work..

Instead of this

```
CollagePictures.InsertOnSubmit(new CollagePicture {Collage = Collage, CollagePicture = existingPic});
```

It should be

```
CollagePictures.InsertOnSubmit(new CollagePicture {Collage = collage, CollagePicture.PictureId = existingPic.PictureId});
```

When you add an object to the relational table entity it adds the object in primary table as well. so just referencing Id makes sure that it does not do anything to the primary table.

It was easy and I should have tried that before..but Thanks for everyone's help though.

Answer (score 0):

What primary key do you have on CollagePicture table? It's not really clear, what do you want to do when inserting new entry to CollagePicture. Do you mean that you add the existing picture to an existing collage? If so your primary key should be (PictureId, CollageId)

Comment: thanks. it is CollagePictureId. But the problem in not collagePicture..problem is Picture table. when I add anything to CollagePicture it automatically inserts record into Picture as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without a detailed view of your data model, it's really hard to take a guess.

If you correctly configured your relations and LINQ to SQL, you could do something like the following:

```
collage.Add(Picture);
```

That way LINQ to SQL would add the right rows to the tables.

To check if the picure already exists in the Collage, you would do something like this.

```
collage.Pictures.Where(p => p.ID == pictureID).Count() > 0
```

Comment: Instead of the last line, you can also write `collage.Pictures.Any(p => p.ID == pictureID)`. In Linq to objects this is much faster (if not an `ICollection`) but I guess in Linq to sql it will be ~the same (depending on the query optimizer). Anyway, it is still prettier :)

Comment: did you mean CollagePicture.Add(picture) ?..problem is not with CollagePicture it is with Picture table.

Answer (score 0):

If the PK of `existingPic` is 0 (assuming type int) then it is new, else it already exists.

```
if(existingPic.pkColumnId == 0)
  CollagePictures.InsertOnSubmit(existingPic);
```

Comment: Thanks...but the problem is not with newer Pic it is with existing pic

Comment: So if its pk > 0 then its not new

Comment: thanks Margus. Please see my edited question again. When I try to add anything to CollagePicture it Adds to the Picture Table as well as Collage Table. It is fine when I have new set of picture and Collage. But if any picture is existing already throw an exception.